# Debugging a the change of a reference value

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have a method call like this:

```
Time processing = BE_ZERO;
DoSomething(DTO& data, Time& processing)
assert(processing== BE_ZERO);
```

DoSomething sends data to a worker depending on the content of data. processing returns the processing time. In this case processing should be 0 but I receive an value != 0.

Now I try to find the place where processing is changed.

I tried to set a Watchpoint on processing but Eclipse told me it's not possible because 
processing is no field.  So I tried to make it to a public member of my class but the same message.

How can I find the place where processing is changed?

Thx

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can use 'Data Breakpoints', where you set a breakpoint that breaks when the data at the memory location `&processing` changes. It's been a long time since I've used Eclipse, perhaps there is a similar feature?

Comment: I thought Watchpoints are the equivalent to this data breakpoints..

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should have checked really. If eclipse doesn't like the `processing` identifier, can you use the IDE to find the address of `processing` yourself and set a watchpoint on that memory location?

Comment: [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_watch.htm) says it needs to be a global variable